# Gson serialized name: "Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gson, eclipse-adt

I'm new to Android, and I'm trying to learn how to use Gson to parse an API call.  I've read around a little bit, and I'm trying to follow this example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

It's going relatively well, but when I imported the project into Eclipse to get a better look at the code, I encountered the error above regarding constructors (as well as a few other confusing errors).

I read some related questions here on StackOverflow, but they all involve inherited classes, and, I may be terribly confused, but I didn't think this class was inherited.

What is causing these errors, and how can I fix them?

If you want a link the the project without digging through the article, it's available here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7215751/JavaCodeGeeks/AndroidJsonParsingTutorial/AndroidJsonProject.zip

Here is the code from the file in question:
package com.javacodegeeks.android.json.model;

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SearchResponse {

public List<Result> results;

@SerializedName("max_id")
public long maxId;

@SerializedName("since_id")
public int sinceId;

@SerializedName("refresh_url")
public String refreshUrl;

@SerializedName("next_page")
public String nextPage;

@SerializedName("results_per_page")
public int resultsPerPage;

public int page;

@SerializedName("completed_in")
public double completedIn;

@SerializedName("since_id_str")
public String sinceIdStr;

@SerializedName("max_id_str")
public String maxIdStr;

public String query;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include whatever class is extending from `Employee`.

Comment: I'm sorry, at first I was confused by you mentioning an `Employee` class, because I've never seen one related to this project.  Then I realized that it was my fault for accidentally copying an error message from a related question that I was looking at.  I apologize for the inconvenience, and I've edited the question to reflect the actual error message.
What are your thoughts now?

Comment: An odd error message. Try adding a default constructor to your bean (`SearchResponse`).

Comment: Well, I figured it out!
It turns out that it wasn't a constructor issue, but rather something having to do with importing the project.
After a few hours of searching StackOverflow, I tried this solution, and it worked:
1)Right click on the project which has issues and select properties
2)Select the appropriate Android build (1.1, 1.5 or 1.5 with google api) and say ok
3)Again right click on the project and select "Android Tools > Fix Project Properties"
Fix the imports once (if required)
4)Refresh the project and you should be ready to go without any manual editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your research is correct - the mentioned error is related to constructors and inheritance.
It seems that somewhere in your project, you have an Employee class, and that class does not declare a public (or at least protected) null constructor (i.e. a constructor that takes no parameters).

In the provided sample code I could not find any mention of such a class - perhaps something you added to experiment with?

Any case, adding a null constructor to the mentioned Employee class should make some of your problems go away.

Comment: I'm sorry, demaniak, at first I was confused by you mentioning an `Employee` class, because I've never seen one related to this project.  Then I realized that it was my fault for accidentally copying an error message from a related question that I was looking at.  I apologize for the inconvenience, and I've edited the question to reflect the actual error message.
What are your thoughts now?

Comment: AH! Ok, so I see above you found the solution! Essentially your entire runtime was missing, so the root of all, "Object" was not found. Hence the error message. But glad you found your solution! Good luck!