# google-play-services_lib unusedStub not compliling

Tags: android, google-play-services

I added google-play-services_lib to my project but I get a compiler error within the unusedStub.java class.

Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Comment: Can you add stacktrace?

Answer (score 7):

I found this fix worked for me [implicit super constructor object() is undefined. must explicitly invoke another constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240708/implicit-super-constructor-object-is-undefined-must-explicitly-invoke-another).

Along with the fix above, go to your Android properties for google-play-services_lib and change your Project Build Target to Android 4.4.2

This fixed the Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined error for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error it was because Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10) was not installed.

To install it go to SDK Manager and tick the box for Android 2.3.3, then hit install and accept license agreements etc. Then restart Eclipse and the error should go away after Eclipse has built all your projects.