# Spring boot error in Application.java package

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor, spring-initializr

hello I just created a project in spring boot initializer but when I import the project in sts I have a set of errors that I do not understand

```
package com.example.filter.influenceur.influenceur;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class InfluenceurApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InfluenceurApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

the errors are :

> The type java.lang.Class cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

> Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit
> constructor

> String cannot be resolved to a type

All this error is in my Application.jave please help me

Comment: Have you tried these threads? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240708/implicit-super-constructor-object-is-undefined-must-explicitly-invoke-another/19570719 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind/25587342#:~:text=Object%20class%20is%20the%20base,jdk%20libs%20in%20your%20buildpath.&text=You%20are%20trying%20to%20point,a%20jre%20and%20not%20jdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These error occurs when JRE is not set for the project. Have a look at [this](http://javahonk.com/implicit-super-constructor-object-is-undefined-for-default-constructor-must-define-an-explicit-constructor/) link to set JRE.

Comment: Do you have an updated link?  It is not loading correctly.